# Possible FeedMePro Anomaly When Trying to Update Table

Tags: plugins, plugin-feedme

I am running into an anomaly when trying to use FeedMe to update existing fields.  My data source is a `CSV` file.  I have a `unique ID`.

I used FMP to create the entries.  Now, I want to update a `table` in each entry with annual sales data.

FMP is set to update existing elements.  My `unique ID` (Line ID) exists in both the entries to be updated and the source `CSV` file.

I have aligned the source CSV file fields to the target entry table fields.  The data preview looks good, with the value for each year correctly aligned.

I also reduced the # of fields being updated to just the table fields and unique ID.

FMP runs the feed with no errors.  But, **the output value for each year in the table is no longer correctly aligned with the assigned year in FMP setup.**  I thought at first it was a templating error on my part, but the values are misaligned in the CP entries.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed in the latest version of Feed Me ([3.0.2.1](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/releases) at time of writing). Do feel free to comment if not, or get in touch via the [Feed Me support channels](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/support/get-support)